# Many to one mapping in spring mvc 3 and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two tables:
writers: writer_id(pk, auto increment), writer_name(varchar)
articles: article_id(pk,auto increment), article_name(varchar),writer_id(fk,int)

one writer can have more than one article. so mapping from articles to writers is many to one.

here is my model for articles:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "article_id")
   private Long articleId;

   @Column(name = "article_name", nullable = false, length=20)
   private String articleName;

   private Writer writer;

   public Writer getWriter() {
       return writer;
   }

   public void setWriter(Writer writer) {
       this.writer = writer;
   }
   //rest of setters and getters
}
```

What will be annotations for writer property?

Heres my controller class:

```
public class ArticleController {
    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addArticle(@ModelAttribute("article") Article article,BindingResult result) {
    return new ModelAndView("addArticle");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveArticle(@ModelAttribute("article") Article article,BindingResult result) {
     articleService.addArticle(article);
     return new ModelAndView("redirect:/articles/list");
    }
}
```

In my addArticle.jsp page, i have populated writers in a select box (which has value of writer_id and label of writer_name).

Please advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option, others are available  :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "writer_fk", nullable = false)
private Writer writer;
```

And in writer you can have

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "writer")
private Set<Article> articles= new HashSet<Article>();
```

Comment: thanks but in saveArticle method, do i have to set article.setWriter(writer) or is it binded to the article (modal attribute)?